# How to unlock PayPal account without phone

Tags: paypal

PayPal make my day, can't pay my invoices, can't access to my account, can't contact support because need anyway verify it by phone or text and my old number is inactive.

Is not even possible to post something on community board. I was able to reset my password to the same by verify my bank number but NO for unlock PayPal account need do it by old phone number that not exists and now somebody else had this number.

Awesome, any idea, I spend like 20 minutes try find something on help page but it always end by login to your PayPal account and verify it by phone.

```
We want to make sure you're the owner of this account

We didn't recognize a device or location that was recently used to log in, so we'd like to confirm your identity.

Just to be safe, we want to make sure that this is your account.
```

___ UPDATE _____

Just pay my invoice just typing credit card number

Answer (score 2):

You can directly call theys from any country. Enter in the contact page:
https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/contact/call

If you have registered a phone in paypal you must login with it.

(you can change the us in the url with your country code).

Comment: Not for my language PL, actually I hate make phone call and spell my details. I can reset my password and type bank number but FF why i have to do it by phone. It is not normal to visit 5 country in one weak ?

Comment: I understand you, but normally when you use your account in one country always and suddenly you try to connect from another, this can be an attack. I think that paypal can't put your money in risk anyway. Anyway facebook do the same and block your account if you travel... I don't say that is a good way to do it, but we can't do nothing with this.

Comment: But all other options are forbidden for recovery account and contact paypal is only possible by phone. What about recovery by email + type credit card number or other details. Google, paypal support suck